# Select query with date field from mySql table returns in datetime.date format in a Python code

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I have a mySQL table with DATE field with value '2017-06-12' but Select date_field query inside a Python file returns in the format (datetime.date(2017, 6, 12),)

How can I print in visual studio code terminal the date field as '2017-06-12'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To convert python datetime object to string,  use **strftime()** attribute.

if the given datetime object is mydate, then use

```
 mydate.strptime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

To know more about the different representations, check here https://strftime.org/